# Publishing two core projects in TFS in one solution causes "...\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' could not be found" error

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a dotNet Core solution containing three projects - one common code, one "read-only" web service and one "admin" web service (which has all the POST, PUT and DELETE routes).  The solution builds just fine locally and works.  I want to build both projects and run both their publish operations to generate the output artifacts as part of the TFS Gated Check-In.

I have a build definition in TFS (2017) which includes a `dotnet build` task in which I specified the two project file paths and which has the following parameters...

> /p:AssemblyVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)
>   /p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber) /p:DeployOnBuild=True
>   /p:PublishProfile=Dev.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
>   /p:Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration)

When the build runs it has no problem with the first project which builds just fine and correctly publishes, but when it then attempts to build the second project it comes up with the error...

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  Restoring packages for e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMOAdmin.WebAPI\JMOAdmin.WebAPI.csproj...
  Restore completed in 23.62 ms for e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMO.DAL\JMO.DAL.csproj.
  Restore completed in 78.55 ms for e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMO.WebAPI\JMO.WebAPI.csproj.
  Restore completed in 34.6 ms for e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMO.WebAPI\JMO.WebAPI.csproj.
  Generating MSBuild file e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMOAdmin.WebAPI\obj\JMOAdmin.WebAPI.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Restore completed in 1.3 sec for e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMOAdmin.WebAPI\JMOAdmin.WebAPI.csproj.
  JMO.DAL -> e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMO.DAL\bin\dev\netcoreapp2.1\JMO.DAL.dll
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMO.WebAPI\publish\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' could not be found [e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMO.WebAPI\JMO.WebAPI.csproj]
Build FAILED.
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMO.WebAPI\publish\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' could not be found [e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMO.WebAPI\JMO.WebAPI.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:03.71
Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : e:\ci\builds\173\s\JMO.WebAPI\develop\JMOAdmin.WebAPI\JMOAdmin.WebAPI.csproj
```

Here's the rub though, if I swap the order of the projects in the task it is still the second project that fails to build.  What is more, if I add a second dotnet build task so there is one for each project it still does the same - the second build fails with the same error, irrespective of which actual project builds first.  The same applies if I use a wildcard for the project file names.

The other thing to note is that the file specified in the error (System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll) is not to be found in either build's output path anyway, whether the build succeeds or not!

The only way I have found so far to get a successful build of both projects is to use the `MultiConfiguration` option with a Pass1,Pass2 value and enable/disable the build tasks so that it takes two entire passes at the process, once for the "read-only" WS and one for the admin WS.  I'm guessing that something is getting stuck in memory during the first project build process and it's tripping up the second but I can't prove it so far.

My problem with this solution is that this only works on the develop branch, on the release branch I need to use the multi-configuration option for the intended purpose - the various target environments (test, uat, prod).

Short of installing a TFS extension to chain builds (not ideal but viable), can anyone suggest why I'm getting this behaviour and, more importantly, suggest a better solution.

Cheers.

Comment: As an interim measure I have installed the TFS extension Build Chain by Majed Elshikh which is working but does create a higher maintenance overhead.